# How to fix alarm notifications issue

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Android alarm notifications using alarm manager stops after 5,6 days if app not open in this period of time.

I set a single alarm for specific time and when it triggers, i set next alarm. This process work fine for 5 to 6 days but after that alarms suddenly stops irrespective of android versions if app does not open for 5,6 days.

I use below code

public void setalarm()
{
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,           AppConstants.ALARM_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
      {
       //lollipop_mr1 is 22, this is only 23 and above                                                                 alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

          }
       else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
       {
          //JB_MR2 is 18, this is only 19 and above.
       alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getTimeInMillis(),  pendingIntent);
        }
        else
        {
          //available since api1
         alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
         }

     }
}
```

//This is broadcast Receiver when alarm trigger

```
public class ReceiverForAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
          onReceive()
          {
            //AlarmTrigger
            //Next Alarm set() 
          }
}
```

Above process working fine for 5,6 days. but after this time period, alarms stopped. it should work continuously without interruption.
Please suggest solution or work around